# Power automate send email 401 Unauthorized: [no body] - Spring RestTemplate

Tags: email, power-automate, spring-resttemplate

We defined email workflow in power automate for sending micro soft’s teams meeting invite, and we tried to send using spring-boot RestTemplate.
However, we are getting error saying “**401 Unauthorized: [no body]**”.

Here is what we tried in sending teams invitation using RestTemplate

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
MultiValueMap<String, String> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
data.add("SUBJECT", "xxx");
data.add("START_TIME", "xxx");
data.add("END_TIME", "xxx");
data.add("ATTENDEES", "xxx");
data.add("TEXT_BODY", "xxx");
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap> entity = new HttpEntity<>(data, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
```

While the same workflow is working sending teams meeting using OKHttp with below code snippet,

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "json formatted string content");
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(<<workflow-url>>).method("POST", body).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

**There is no authentication/authorization details are provided while sending teams meeting request using OkHttp.**

Any clue, where we are going wrong?

Comment: What does this have to do with PowerAutomate?

Comment: nothing to do with PowerAutomate, something is missing while making call from RestTemplate. The PowerAutomate url might b having authentication/authorization details.